# Find -exec grep in if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep, find

I have a if statement like this and I can't make it work:

```
if find "$DIRECTORY" -name "$FILE" "$OPTION1" "$OPTION2" -exec grep -l -q $CONTENT {} \;
```

find paths must precede expression...

I tried \'"$FILE"\' , \'$FILE\' same result.

Comment: should be -name not -NAME

Comment: What are the values of all of those variables? (Specifically `DIRECTORY`, `OPTION1` and `OPTION2`.)

Comment: DIRECTORY tested with simple /home/whatever, OPTION1 OPTION2 are find options, can be empty ? may this be the problem?

Comment: Presumably `"OPTION1"` and `"OPTION2"` should be `"$OPTION1"` and `"$OPTION2"` also

Comment: Empty values for `OPTION1` and `OPTION2` are going to cause a `find` error I think but not this error. Can you add `set -x` to the script above this line and find the **exact** executed line that causes this error?

Comment: find /home/student -name script2.sh -exec grep -l -q echo '{}' ';'||| I removed   all quotation marks and it works kinda but its always true even if file doesnt exist.